# Apache httpd proxy:reverse error

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, reverse-proxy

I have a apache server that handle normal http request for a mobile game. It is like average 2-4 request per second and every thing is working smoothly.  However, a unexpected error occur every few hours and it makes apache busy and hold apache for a while, like 1-2 minute. As a result the request receive during the period is accumulated and handle at the same time until apache is back to available. This makes each single request execution time to 60 - 270 second and it is not acceptable. Here is my error log in apache that cause the problem:

```
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:15 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11444 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:15 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:15 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11444 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:17 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11445 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:17 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:17 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11445 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11446 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11446 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11447 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:18 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11447 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11448 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11448 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11449 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11449 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11450 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11450 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11451 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:19 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11451 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:26 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11454 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:26 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:26 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11454 for (*)
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:34 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1820): proxy: grabbed scoreboard slot 0 in child 11456 for worker proxy:reverse
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:34 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1839): proxy: worker proxy:reverse already initialized
[Mon Jan 20 08:05:34 2014] [debug] proxy_util.c(1936): proxy: initialized single connection worker 0 in child 11456 for (*)
```

The apache setting are:

```
StartServers       8
MinSpareServers    5
MaxSpareServers   20
ServerLimit      256
MaxClients       1024
MaxRequestsPerChild 4000

ProxyRequest On
```

Are there any wrong with my setting? Is this problem related to proxy setting?
I have been searching on the web for 2-3 day, but still have not get the solution. Hope you guys can help. Thank you so much.